# RoR - Automated processes that send emails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, automation

I need to send a number of emails out from my RoR application, and would like some advice on how best to do this.

Previous questions (e.g. [RoR - where to put a automated process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039208/ror-where-to-put-a-automated-process)) place all the code in the model. However - Because I'm sending out an email, I'm going to have to access an email View. It would seem that the model is not the best place for this.

Should I be putting this process in a controller? If so, what's the best way to initiate it from a cronjob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 3, you'd set up an ActiveMailer class in app/mailers/, put the view templates in app/views/ and you could then send emails correctly once your environment is set up.

To access your mailer and actually do the sending, you could set up a Rake task in lib/tasks/cron.rake that requires the environment, like so:

```
namespace :cron

  desc "Sends some emails"
  task :send_emails => [:environment] do 
    MailerName.some_email(:some_option => 'w00t').deliver
  end

end
```

You could then hit this rake task by running a bash shell script somthing like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
export GEM_PATH=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
cd "/users/yourname/railsapp"
/usr/local/bin/rake cron:send_emails RAILS_ENV=production
```

Note that this is going to load your entire environment on every run.  If you're doing *lots* of emails, you may find it works better to use `curl` to periodically hit a specific url on your server, so that you use the existing server Rails instances instead of spinning up a new one on every run.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rails 3.x, you can place them in app/mailers. Otherwise you can use the lib folder for this purpose.

If the functionality is huge you can split them into separate files and use the following directory structure:

```
lib/notifier/a.rb
lib/notifier/b.rb
```

and so on

Comment: If I put them into app/mailers, where do I place the email View files. currently these are in the views\classname folder. Is this going to work from outside the main rails application?